# PostgreSQL: changing data directory location (sshfs)

Tags: postgresql-9.4, errors, remote, startup

I'm trying to change my PostgreSQL data directory initially on my Debian server to my NAS (running also on linux).
To do so, I've mounted it on a specific directory through sshfs (in /mnt/titanBDD).

Now I get this error when starting postgre (using service and pg_ctlcluster):

> Error: could not exec /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/pg_ctl
>   /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/pg_ctl start -D
>   /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/redirect_TITAN -l
>   /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.4-main.log -s -o  -c
>   config_file="/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf"

Here is the modified part of postgresql.conf:

```
data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main'
```

modified in:

```
data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/redirect_TITAN'
```

Where redirect_TITAN:

```
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 nov.   1 16:23 /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/redirect_TITAN -> /mnt/titanBDD/main
```

I've used the following command to move my data:

```
root@machine:~# cp --preserve=all -R /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main/ /mnt/titanBDD/
```

Acutally, in /mnt/titanBDD I have:

```
root@machine:~# ls -als /mnt/titanBDD/
total 12
4 drwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres 4096 nov.   1 16:19 .
4 drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root     4096 nov.   1 14:05 ..
4 drwx------ 1 postgres postgres 4096 nov.   1 15:59 main
```

What is going wrong? I guess it's a context issue but don't have any idea where to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem using `-o allow_other` when mounting the `/mnt/titanBDD` with `sshfs`.

The error message was still :

> Error: could not exec
>
> ```
> /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/pg_ctl 
> start -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/redirect_TITAN
> -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.4-main.log -s -o -c
> config_file="/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf"
> ```

(which repeat the command twice?!)

when executing:

```
usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/pg_ctl 
start -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/redirect_TITAN
-l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.4-main.log -s -o -c
config_file="/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf"
```

but I noticed the user `postgres` didn't have access to the mounted point which put me on the track.

Now PostgreSQL starts without any problem.